# Firebase Storage Resumable Uploading Large Files on web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I cannot find any document for resumable upload even browser is closed or tab is closed.Is there any way for doing resumable upload ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK can't resume an upload after the browser tab is closed (or after and Android app or iOS app is killed).  Once the context of the upload is lost, it doesn't come back.

When the SDK claims that uploads are "resumable", that refers to the fact the if the user's internet connection is lost, but returns later (while the app is still running), the upload will pick up where it left off.

Comment: Hmm I thought like this, thank your sharing the correct answer.